# Upload values from Python list to MySql using selfwritten function

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have a list of values parsed from csv. the list includef information stored like in dictionary,I need to upload values from the list to MySql, tried to write a function, but an error occures.Error text :
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Nokia' VALUE 'Manufacturer'' at line 1")

```
data = ["Manufacturer", "Nokia"]

def upload(what, where):
    import MySQLdb as db
    con = db.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='somepass', db='test')
    #connecting to MySql
    cursor = con.cursor()
    insertvalue = "a"

    if what in where:
        x = where.index(what)
        x += 1
        insertitem = where[x]
    else:
        insertitem = "Not Available"

    query = "INSERT INTO phone_db %s VALUE %s"# (where to insert),(What to insert)
    args = (insertitem, what)
    #cursor.execute(query,args)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: I think I can see what the problem is, but I don't get what your code is doing to get there. Can you add the test you are doing or further explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL query don't specify the columns that you are trying to fill with information.

Since you are using the '%s' syntax, python thinks you are trying to insert a string and not a column name, and it adds "'".

If you really want to specify the column this way (which is not recommended to say the least), you should do:

```
query = "INSERT INTO phone_db ({column}) VALUES (%s)".format(column = insertitem)
args = (what,)
cursor.execute(query,args)
```

More about the MySQL insert syntax and Python can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html